# парсинг кириллических ссылок PHP

Tags: php

Как парсить подобные ссылки:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('http://synonymonline.ru/П/прекрасный'); ?>
```

пробовал с urlencode и rawurlencode, iconv - ничего не помогает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя просто взять ссылку и пропустить ее целиком через `urlencode()` или `rawurlencode()`. На выходе вы получите уже не ссылку.

Для вашего случая нужно выделить из ссылке `path`, разбить его на составляющие, их прогнать через функцию [rawurlencode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.rawurlencode.php) и собрать все назад.

Пример:

```
$arr = parse_url('http://synonymonline.ru/П/прекрасный');
$link = $arr['scheme'] . '://' 
      . $arr['host']
      . implode('/', 
            array_map('rawurlencode', 
                explode('/', $arr['path'])
            )
        );
echo file_get_contents($link);
```

P.S. Если у вас домен будет содержать символы отличные от латинских, то его придется переводить в формат IDNA ASCII с использованием [idn_to_ascii()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.idn-to-ascii.php)

Answer (score 0):

В моём случае целевая ссылка имела вид

```
http://some.domain.org//Uploads/images/408/А,Б%20секция%203%20этаж%204%20квcrop.jpg
```

т.е. смесь бульдога с носорогом - и слэши лишние, и нелатиница, и пробел в форме `%20` .

Помогло следующее решение, по мотивам *Andr'U Sender* с тостера (*так вышло, сначала ответил [там](https://toster.ru/q/85232)*), плюс добавил развёрнутый рабочий пример по **кириллическим доменам** (и др. национальным) по наводке *@Visman* :

Код проверен под PHP 7.2:

```
if (preg_match('#^([\w\d]+://)([^/]+)(.*)$#iu', $filenameSrc, $m)){
    $filenameSrc = $m[1] . idn_to_ascii($m[2], IDNA_DEFAULT, INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46) . $m[3];
}
$filenameSrc = urldecode($filenameSrc);
$filenameSrc = rawurlencode($filenameSrc); 
$filenameSrc = str_replace(array('%3A','%2F'), array(':', '/'), $filenameSrc);
```

Замечу, что если пытаться использовать `urlencode`, а не `rawurlencode`, то тот кодирует пробелы в "`+`" плюсы и ссылка открываться не желала в таком виде. А с `%20` как делает `rawurlencode` - прокатило.

Надеюсь тут тоже кому-то спасёт немного волос :)