# Конвертировать URL PHP

Tags: php

Есть строка вида - 1 строка:

```
http://site/search/%E6%E5%EB%E5%E7%ED%FB%E9%20%F7%E5%EB%EE%E2%E5%EA/
```

И есть своя строка -  2 строка:

```
 http://site/search/железный_человек
```

Необходимо конвертировать кодировку в урле, чтобы привести 2 строку в виде первой.

Comment: Что вы делали для решения своей задачи? Какие проблемы у вас возникли?

Comment: То есть вместо нижнего подчёркивания должен быть %20? Это точно?

Comment: Вы все еще работаете в кодировке cp1251? Решение похожей задачи тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685459/186083

Comment: Как мне это применить к моему случаю?

Answer (score 2):

Для этого есть стандартная функция [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php)

```
echo 'http://site/search/' . urlencode('железный_человек');
// http://site/search/%E6%E5%EB%E5%E7%ED%FB%E9%20%F7%E5%EB%EE%E2%E5%EA
```

Comment: А если нет возможности разделить строку так, как разделили вы в ответе?

Comment: Кстати, ваш код работает неправильно. Запустите его, и увидите, что результат не тот, кодируется по-другому.

Comment: @andreymal, тогда уточните в вопросе алгоритм, по которому необходимо закодировать строку. Эта функция будет кодировать все символы, которые используются при разборе URL-адресов, поэтому просто скормить ей весь URL не получится. Так само не получится сделать это с любой другой существующей функцией, вам необходимо сначала разделить строку либо написать свою функцию, которая, например, будет заменять только кириллицу. Уточните вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вопрос-то не мой)

Comment: @andreymal привычка работы с клиентами, простите)

Comment: Я выяснил, что пробел заменяется не на подчеркивание, а на "%20".

Comment: не работает код, описанный выше. (ответ от therainycat)

Comment: он работает, но отличается от изначального. поэтому если вставить его, то выдаст 404 ошибку.

Comment: Фраза "железный человек" |
URL "%E6%E5%EB%E5%E7%ED%FB%E9%20%F7%E5%EB%EE%E2%E5%EA" - осталось найти чем кодировать.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось все проще некуда. Вот этот код у меня заработал.

```
$url = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', 'бэтмэн');
$urlis = urlencode($url);
$urlisi = 'http://site/torrentz/search/';
$urls = $urlisi.$urlis; 
$urls = str_replace('+', ' ', $urls);
echo $urls . "/";
```

Может кому поможет. Я его немного оптимизирую.